# Do prospective employers usually call or email for scheduling interviews?

Tags: resume, employees, human-resources

I know there is no direct answer to this but i am hoping those have been through the process or are HR managers can help me with this.

I sent out resumes to maybe 5-8 places and it had my old phone number on it.  I do however, have the same email address that's on there.  Do HR managers usually call to schedule an interview or do they usually email first and then follow up via phone calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience it can be either.

The main indicator is probably if they've already talked to you in some fashion already, that's one thing, and if so they'd probably try your number and then your email.

If they *haven't* talked to you so far, which sounds like the case...  Well if they try to call and can't reach you either they:

- aren't that interested and give up.
  or
- are interested and try email too.

Either way you can either send them a very brief email "Just wanted to let you know that I recently applied for x but my phone number has changed to y" or do nothing.  Anything beyond a brief note is weird.  Remember you can also use regular mail too if you don't have their email.

Comment: Some will automatically try both. They know that it can be hard to reach people during the day if they limit themselves to only one method.

Comment: +1 with follow up with a note about your new contact details. (And next time, go over those resumés with a fine-toothed comb before sending them out... who knows what other mistakes may be lurking in there?)